# Existing host keys found error when ssh in gcp vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

When running `gcloud beta compute ssh --zone xxx --internal-ip --project xxx xxx`

I am getting the following error but some of my colleagues work just fine and ssh in without any issue.

```
Existing host keys found in /Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

May I ask what can be the reason causing this and what can I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that a host with the same IP address but with a different fingerprint was found in the known hosts file. This can happen when you create and delete instances and the same external public IP address is used for the VM instance. The fingerprint will be different for the new host (VM instance).

Edit the file `/Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`, find the entry for the VM's IP address and remove the entry.

Comment: Thanks, John,  I double-checked that there is no IP address in the file, it has the following format :   compute.xxxx ssh-ed25519 xxxxxxxx  compute.xxxx ssh-rsa xxxx compute.xxxxxx ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xxxx

Comment: @Ken The file can use hostnames or IP addresses. In your case hostnames. My suggestion is to delete the file and it will be recreated.

Comment: Thanks @John ,  btw sometimes for me during the generation, I got the following error : Writing 3 keys to /Users/xxxx/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].  do you know why this happened?

Comment: @Ken - I would need more details. In the context of "known hosts", three keys does not make sense unless the wording is "host keys".